# Last div fill remaining height

Tags: html, css

I want to make the last `div` in my `body` to fill the remaining space but I'm having some trouble. I have this HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="content"></div>    
  <div class="footer"></div> 
</body>
```

and this CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr5pk75b/).

It's not working because a vertical scrollbar is appearing.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: Do you want your `content` `div` to be dynamic (variable height)?

Comment: yes, variable height ..

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a calculation:

```
.footer {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Also, add this style:

```
body,html {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/pctLkm5q/)

---

If the height of `content` is unknown, you can use a flexbox solution:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  flex: 1;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/aew26ydb/)**

Comment: no not possible, because i don't know the height of all the previous div (in the exemple i write 100px as an exemple)

Comment: I've added a flexbox solution.